# Change log-level via mocking

Tags: python, logging

I want to change the log-level temporarily.

My current strategy is to use mocking.

```
with mock.patch(...):
    my_method_which_does_log()
```

All `logging.info()` calls inside the method should get ignored and not logged to the console.

How to implement the `...` to make logs of level INFO get ignored?

The code is single-process and single-thread and executed during testing only.

Comment: Is your code single-threaded/single-process and should it change logging only from within that `with` block or for everything called by the code in that `with` block?

Comment: Could you add more info how you currently log? For example using simple calls to `logging.info` or using a custom `logging.Logger`? Also are you using [streams for logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler)? Also what should happen to logging levels below info (`logging.debug`)? Should they be printed or also hidden? As it currently stands it's too broad because there are a lot (too many) of cases to be considered here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `How to mock my_method_which_does_log`, why would you mock the actual method?

Comment: Are you trying to influence a single logger, e.g. the root logger returned by `getLogger()`, or multiple loggers, e.g. the called code involves multiple modules and each one does `getLogger(__name__)`?

Comment: @cryptoplex I want to change the log level of all loggers.

Comment: I found a library: http://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to change the log-level temporarily.

A way to do this without mocking is [`logging.disable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.disable)

```
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        logging.disable(logging.WARNING)

    def tearDown(self):
        logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
```

This example would only show messages of level `WARNING` and above for each test in the `TestSomething` class. (You call `disable` at the start and end of each test as needed. This seems a bit cleaner.)

To unset this temporary throttling, call `logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)`:

> If `logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)` is called, it effectively removes this overriding level, so that logging output again depends on the effective levels of individual loggers.

Comment: I am unsure if `logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)` does a clean reset to the original state. Imagine before `logging.disable(logging.ERROR)` was called before I disable the logging. Then finally the state would be different. But don't get me wrong. This solution is good, much better then no solution!

Comment: @guettli: `logging.NOTSET` seems to completely reset the behavior of  individual loggers

Comment: if `logging.disable(logging.INFO)` was done before my code was called, the after my code the reset does reset too much.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think mocking is going to do what you want. The loggers are presumably already instantiated in this scenario, and `level` is an instance variable for each of the loggers (and also any of the handlers that each logger has).

You can create a custom context manager. That would look something like this:

#### Context Manager

```
import logging

class override_logging_level():

    "A context manager for temporarily setting the logging level"

    def __init__(self, level, process_handlers=True):
        self.saved_level      = {}
        self.level            = level
        self.process_handlers = process_handlers

    def __enter__(self):

        # Save the root logger
        self.save_logger('', logging.getLogger())

        # Iterate over the other loggers
        for name, logger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.items():

            self.save_logger(name, logger)

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):

        # Restore the root logger
        self.restore_logger('', logging.getLogger())

        # Iterate over the loggers
        for name, logger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.items():

            self.restore_logger(name, logger)

    def save_logger(self, name, logger):

        # Save off the level
        self.saved_level[name] = logger.level

        # Override the level
        logger.setLevel(self.level)

        if not self.process_handlers:
            return

        # Iterate over the handlers for this logger
        for handler in logger.handlers:

            # No reliable name. Just use the id of the object
            self.saved_level[id(handler)] = handler.level

    def restore_logger(self, name, logger):

        # It's possible that some intervening code added one or more loggers...
        if name not in self.saved_level:
            return

        # Restore the level for the logger
        logger.setLevel(self.saved_level[name])

        if not self.process_handlers:
            return

        # Iterate over the handlers for this logger
        for handler in logger.handlers:

            # Reconstruct the key for this handler
            key = id(handler)

            # Again, we could have possibly added more handlers
            if key not in self.saved_level:
                continue

            # Restore the level for the handler
            handler.setLevel(self.saved_level[key])
```

#### Test Code

```
# Setup for basic logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

# Create some loggers - the root logger and a couple others
lr = logging.getLogger()
l1 = logging.getLogger('L1')
l2 = logging.getLogger('L2') 

# Won't see this message due to the level
lr.info("lr - msg 1")
l1.info("l1 - msg 1")
l2.info("l2 - msg 1")

# Temporarily override the level
with override_logging_level(logging.INFO):

    # Will see
    lr.info("lr - msg 2")
    l1.info("l1 - msg 2")
    l2.info("l2 - msg 2")

# Won't see, again...
lr.info("lr - msg 3")
l1.info("l1 - msg 3")
l2.info("l2 - msg 3")
```

#### Results

```
$ python ./main.py
INFO:root:lr - msg 2
INFO:L1:l1 - msg 2
INFO:L2:l2 - msg 2
```

#### Notes

- The code would need to be enhanced to support multithreading; for example, `logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict` is a shared variable that's guarded by locks in the `logging` code.

Comment: This looks good. I used the term "mocking", but actually a context-manager does solve this, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using @cryptoplex's approach of using Context Managers, here's the [official version from the logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-context-manager-for-selective-logging):

> ```
> import logging
> import sys
>
> class LoggingContext(object):
>     def __init__(self, logger, level=None, handler=None, close=True):
>         self.logger = logger
>         self.level = level
>         self.handler = handler
>         self.close = close
>
>     def __enter__(self):
>         if self.level is not None:
>             self.old_level = self.logger.level
>             self.logger.setLevel(self.level)
>         if self.handler:
>             self.logger.addHandler(self.handler)
>
>     def __exit__(self, et, ev, tb):
>         if self.level is not None:
>             self.logger.setLevel(self.old_level)
>         if self.handler:
>             self.logger.removeHandler(self.handler)
>         if self.handler and self.close:
>             self.handler.close()
>         # implicit return of None => don't swallow exceptions
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to pass the logger instance to the method you are testing. It is a bit more invasive though since you are changing your method a little, however it gives you more flexibility.

Add the logger parameter to your method signature, something along the lines of:

```
def my_method( your_other_params, logger):
    pass
```

In your unit test file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # define the logger you want to use:
    logging.basicConfig( stream=sys.stderr )
    logging.getLogger( "MyTests.test_my_method" ).setLevel( logging.DEBUG )

...

def test_my_method(self):
    test_logger = logging.getLogger( "MyTests.test_my_method" )
    # pass your logger to your method    
    my_method(your_normal_parameters, test_logger)
```

python logger docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: Hmmm this means I need to change my code an pass around `logger`, yes this definitely works. But I am unsure if I want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern to write all logs to a list. It ignores logs of level INFO and smaller.

```
logs=[]

import logging
def my_log(logger_self, level, *args, **kwargs):
    if level>logging.INFO:
        logs.append((args, kwargs))

with mock.patch('logging.Logger._log', my_log):
    my_method_which_does_log()
```